# I have a problem with it when i use Powerlevel10k which is a theme for ZSH?

Tags: oh-my-zsh

I have a problem with it when i use Powerlevel10k which is a theme for ZSH?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the [Powerlevel10k FAQ](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k/blob/master/README.md#what-do-different-symbols-in-git-status-mean):

> **Q: What do different symbols in Git status mean?**
>
> When using *Lean*, *Classic* or *Rainbow* style, Git status may look like this:
>
> ```
> feature:master ⇣42⇡42 *42 merge ~42 +42 !42 ?42
> ```
>
> Legend:
>
> ```
> | Symbol  | Meaning                                                           | Source                                               |
> | --------| ------------------------------------------------------------------| ---------------------------------------------------- |
> | feature | current branch; replaced with #tag or @commit if not on a branch  | git status                                           |
> | master  | remote tracking branch; only shown if different from local branch | git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic-full-name @{u} |
> | ⇣42     | this many commits behind the remote                               | git status                                           |
> | ⇡42     | this many commits ahead of the remote                             | git status                                           |
> | *42     | this many stashes                                                 | git stash list                                       |
> | merge   | repository state                                                  | git status                                           |
> | ~42     | this many merge conflicts                                         | git status                                           |
> | +42     | this many staged changes                                          | git status                                           |
> | !42     | this many unstaged changes                                        | git status                                           |
> | ?42     | this many untracked files                                         | git status                                           |
> ```
>
> See also: [How do I change the format of Git status?](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k/blob/master/README.md#how-do-i-change-the-format-of-git-status)

If you've created a Git repository at the root of your home directory to store dotfiles, you probably want to ignore untracked files in it. You can achieve this by executing the following command:

```sh
git -C ~ config status.showuntrackedfiles no
```

This will have several effects:

- `git status` will be faster.
- `git status` won't list 171 untracked files.
- `?171` will disappear from your prompt.

You can undo the above command with the following command:

```sh
git -C ~ config --unset status.showuntrackedfiles
```

if you don't want to see Git status in your prompt while in home directory, add this parameter to `~/.p10k.zsh`:

```
# Don't display Git status in prompt for Git repositories whose workdir matches
# this pattern.
typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_VCS_DISABLED_WORKDIR_PATTERN='~'
```

If you don't want to see Git status in your prompt at all, remove `vcs` from `POWERLEVEL9K_LEFT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS` array in `~/.p10k.zsh`.